# Palindrome tester gives False for 11 but returns True for 121

Tags: python, palindrome

Here is my code:

```
def isPalindrome(x):
    if x < 0 or (x % 10 == 0 and x != 0):
        return False
    rev = 0
    while x > rev:
        rev = (rev*10 + x % 10)
        x /= 10
    return x == rev or x == rev/10

x = 11
print(isPalindrome(x))
```

Why does this code not give the desired results for all positive integer inputs?

Comment: Did this help you out?  I'm just going back and checking answers I posted to see if I can help more or if I can figure out why my answer wasn't accepted or upvoted by the person who asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two problems.

The first is that `x /= 10` performs a floating point divide, so `11 /= 10` is `1.1`, not `1`.  Integer divide in Python is `//`.

The second is that you don't want to keep looping while `x > rev` but rather while `x > 0` because you want to reverse every digit of your number.  When `x > 0`, you still have digits in `x` that you haven't added to the reversed value.  The accumulated portion of the reversed value being greater than the part of the answer still to be processed doesn't mean anything.

So here's a working version of your code, at least for your two test cases and a few more I did.  I didn't do an exhaustive test.

```
def isPalindrome(x):
    if x < 0 or (x % 10 == 0 and x != 0):
        return False
    rev = 0
    y = x
    while y > 0:
        rev = (rev*10 + y % 10)
        y //= 10
    return x == rev or x == rev/10
```